# Type hints for dynamically added attributes

Tags: python, class, types, type-hinting

I want mypy not to signal errors in the following situation:

```
FOO = {"bar": 42}

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, params: Dict[str, Any]):
        for name, value in params.items():
            setattr(self, name, value)

foo = Foo(FOO)
foo.bar  # <-- mypy flags this, saying '"Foo" has no attribute "bar"'
```

In essence I want type annotations for attributes I have added dynamically from a dict, where I don't know a-priori the keys of said dict. I tried overwriting `Foo.__annotations__` using the dict, but no success. Maybe I'm trying to do something particularly unPythonic, but I really appreciate having type-hints when writing/debugging code, so it would be amazing to have this functionality somehow.

Comment: What version of Python are you running?

Comment: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5719

Comment: @ilovebees Currently 3.8, but open to upgrading

Comment: @Nin17 thanks. I was hoping that `__annotations__` or some other trick could work... Not looking promising.